# Optional Fields in Hibernate Embeddable Class

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an Embeddedable class, Address. The idea is to use @AttributeOverride(s) to map to a legacy database schema. However, I want the fields to be optional. For example, not every record has a STREET_ADDRESS_2.

The class below persists/saves to the database fine, but blows up with "java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found" when doing a getAll() operation. Specifically, the getStreet2() method causes issues.

```
@Embeddable
public class Address implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private String street1;
private String street2;
private String state;
private String zip;
private String city;
private String phone;

@Column(name = "STREET1", updatable=false, insertable=false)
public String getStreet1() {
    return street1;
}

public void setStreet1(String street1) {
    this.street1 = street1;
}

//@Basic(optional=true)
@Column(name="STREET2", insertable=false, updatable=false)
@NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
public String getStreet2() {
    return street2;
}

public void setStreet2(String street2) {
    this.street2 = street2;
}

@Column(name="STATE", updatable=false, insertable=false)
public String getState() {
    return state;
}

public void setState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
}

@Column(name="ZIP", updatable=false, insertable=false)
public String getZip() {
    return zip;
}

public void setZip(String zip) {
    this.zip = zip;
}

@Column(name="CITY", updatable=false, insertable=false)
public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

@Column(name="PHONE", updatable=false, insertable=false)
public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Address [street1=" + street1 + ", street2=" + street2
            + ", state=" + state + ", zip=" + zip + ", city=" + city
            + ", phone=" + phone + "]";
}
```

The call to use the Embedded class looks like this:

```
@Embedded
@AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name = "street1", column = @Column(name = "PERSON_STREET_1")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "street2", column = @Column(name = "PERSON_STREET_2")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "city", column = @Column(name = "PERSON_CITY")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "state", column = @Column(name = "PERSON_STATE")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "zip", column = @Column(name = "PERSON_ZIP")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "phone", column = @Column(name = "SOLDIER_PHONE")) })
@NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
public Address getPersonAddress() {
    return personAddress;
}

public void setPersonAddress(Address personAddress) {
    this.personAddress = personAddress;
}

@Embedded
@AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name = "street1", column = @Column(name = "DEPARTMENT_STREET")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "city", column = @Column(name = "DEPARTMENT_CITY")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "state", column = @Column(name = "DEPARTMENT_STATE")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "zip", column = @Column(name = "DEPARTMENT_ZIP")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "phone", column = @Column(name = "UNIT_PHONE")) })
public Address getDepartmentAddress() {
    return DepartmentAddress;
}

public void setDepartmentAddress(Address DepartmentAddress) {
    this.DepartmentAddress = DepartmentAddress;
}
```

It seems to blow up because the Department address doesn't have a Street2 in the database to override.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

In JPA there is no concept of deriving only subset of the attribute mappings from Embeddable. Each time you use @Embedded in entity, all the attributes of Embeddable become attributes of entity with their default mappings. As in you case, you can override attributes (and associations as well), but you cannot remove them.

Also I am not aware of vendor specific support for this in Hibernate.